# Pairwise Euclidean distance search algorithm

Tags: python, performance, comparative-review, numpy

- x and y are two-dimensional arrays with dimensions (AxN) and (BxN), i.e. they have the same number of columns.
- I need to get a matrix of Euclidean distances between each pair of rows from x and y.

I have already written four different methods that give equally good results. But the first three methods are not fast enough, and the fourth method consumes too much memory.

1:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return distance.cdist(x, y)
```

2:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    res = []
    one_res = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            one_res.append(math.sqrt(sum(x[i] ** 2) + sum(y[j] ** 2) - 2 * 
               np.dot(x[i], np.transpose(y[j]))))
        res.append(one_res)
        one_res = []
    return res
```

3:

```
import numpy as np

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    distances = np.zeros((x.T[0].shape[0], y.T[0].shape[0]))
    for x, y in zip(x.T, y.T):
        distances = np.subtract.outer(x, y) ** 2 + distances
    return np.sqrt(distances)
```

4:

```
import numpy as np


def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
    y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)
    return np.sqrt(((x - y) ** 2).sum(-1))
```

It looks like the second way could still be improved, and it also shows the best timing. Can you help me with the optimization, please?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review@SE. Time allowing, (re?)visit [How to get the best value out of Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436). As per [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), the title of a CR question (*and*, preferably, [the code itself](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)) should state what the code is to accomplish.

Comment: It may help the non-mathheads if you added why&how 2-4 compute the distances. Please add how the result is going to be used - e.g, for comparisons, you don't need sqrt (`cdist(x, y, 'sqeuclidean')`). Do you need all values at once/as a matrix? Otherwise, a *generator* may help. What are typical dimensions of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Performance:

A way to use broadcasting but avoid allocating the 3d array is to separate the distance formula into $(x - y) ** 2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy$.

```
squared_matrix = np.sum(A ** 2,axis=1 )[:,np.newaxis] - 2 * (A@B.T) + np.sum(B ** 2,axis=1 )[np.newaxis,:]
distance_matrix = np.sqrt(squared_matrix)
```

Check:

```
np.allclose(distance_matrix,euclidean_distance(A,B))
>>> True
```

Comment: You can probably write this with np.einsum in a more succinct way but einsum makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 2):

sklearn's library Euclidean distance calculation was tested to perform better than scipy & numpy due to used vectorisation implementation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimising-pairwise-euclidean-distance-calculations-using-python-fc020112c984) . Codes were compared:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

vec = np.array([ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ],
            [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ] ])  
######################## 1
scipy_cdist = cdist(vec, vec, metric='euclidean')
print(scipy_cdist)

######################## 2
sklearn_dist = euclidean_distances(vec, vec)
print(sklearn_dist)

########################  3  
#  method consuming memory.
x = np.sum(vec**2, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
y = np.sum(vec**2,    axis=1)
xy = np.dot(vec, vec.T)
dist = np.sqrt(x + y - 2*xy)
print(dist)

######################## 4
# Without pre-allocating memory
dist = []
for i in range(len(vec)):
    dist.append(((vec- vec[i])**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5)
print("Without pre-allocating memory:\n", np.array(dist, dtype= float))

# pre-allocating memory
D = np.empty((len(vec),len(vec)))
for i in range(len(vec)):
    D[i, :] = ((vec-vec[i])**2).sum(axis=1)**0.5
print("pre-allocating memory:\n", D)
```

plus preallocation of memory can influence the performance...
can see by link testing_code to compare all these 4 approaches

Comment: This is missing `norm()`. Also, for most intents, anything linked doesn't exist. You need to paste times and analyses here.

Comment: why norm() is missing? Euclidean is 2-norm. I corrected the code to its  simpliest version to be reproducible, think that adding more complicated multidimensional array & timing will not become too hard for unbelievers. The fourth approach with memory-preallocation I'm not going to test myself - i don't need it, as I believe to the link (I also checked) -- but this can be the advice for topic-starter if he still wants to save memory - or you can invest your own time if you doubt about the conclusion I've already done from the article - sklearn performs the best

Comment: BTW, scipy's debugging messages seems more explaining than sklearn's ones, therefore the choice of the library is developer's choice anyway

Comment: added memory_preallocation from link's example ... but still it is a little worth

Answer (score 1):

Ideas for `2`:

- preallocate `res`
- don't use `one_res`, just a comprehensions

Comment: (There's [`_cdist_callable()`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/distance.py).)